# Using CSS3 to animate opening a tile on 2x2 quadrant design

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

So I have a design that has four quadrant layout. Very similar to https://www.xfinityoffers.com/?exp=mobile but I want it to be responsive and adjust by it's container. Also, important to note it won't just be images like in that example. It's important for me to animate the opening of each tile so the user can see the tile expand to cover his 3 buddies and take up the full size of the container.

Here's a codepen of basically what I have so far - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwpvvw
I tried making the active tile

```
.tile.active {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

but that doesn't help with an animation because it starts in the top left corner rather than it's actual location. Any insight or any other examples of similar functionality in the wild would be super helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sktkkoj3/4/). The z-index is that big on the active class because transition affects z-index as well, meaning it will take 0.3 seconds to get from the initial value to the new one. This in turn means that if the zindexes are 0 and 1 you'll see the overlap at the end.

Because of the nature of your animation i think that js will suffice, however you can modify it as you need`.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to grow when you hover over it, this code will work.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 230px;
  height: 220px;
  }

#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  transition: height .5s, width .5s;
  z-index: 1;
  }

#div1:Hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  }

#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  }

#div3 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  }

#div4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <p>Div 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <p>Div 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```